# Loop issue with an API about Bitcoin price

Tags: python, api, finance

I use an API to have an update of the Bitcoin price.

The following code give me a lot of informations :

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', params={
    'function': 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
    'from_currency': 'BTC', 
    'to_currency': 'EUR',
    'apikey': AV_API_KEY
})
resp

resp.json()
```

output :

```
{'Realtime Currency Exchange Rate': {'1. From_Currency Code': 'BTC',
  '2. From_Currency Name': 'Bitcoin',
  '3. To_Currency Code': 'EUR',
  '4. To_Currency Name': 'Euro',
  '5. Exchange Rate': '16006.64235500',
  '6. Last Refreshed': '2020-11-30 14:12:04',
  '7. Time Zone': 'UTC',
  '8. Bid Price': '16006.64235500',
  '9. Ask Price': '16006.65069000'}}
```

I want to only have the 5. Exchange rate and to update the price every 10 seconds, so I tried this :

```
resp = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', params={
    'function': 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
    'from_currency': 'BTC', 
    'to_currency': 'EUR',
    'apikey': AV_API_KEY
})
resp

resp.json()
a=resp.json() 

def update_price_10sec():
    print(a.get('Realtime Currency Exchange Rate').get('5. Exchange Rate')) 

while True:
    update_price_10sec()
    time.sleep(10) #make function to sleep for 10 seconds
```

output is then :

```
16006.64235500
16006.64235500
16006.64235500
16006.64235500
16006.64235500
(etc...)
```

So the problem is that the price is no more updated, and every 10 sec I have a copy paste of the last known price. Do someone know how can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you somehow expecting that the value of `a` should change every time you call the function? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem you need to put the request inside the while loop.

```
def GET():
    resp = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', params={
        'function': 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
        'from_currency': 'BTC', 
        'to_currency': 'EUR',
        'apikey': AV_API_KEY
    })

    return resp.json() 

def update_price_10sec(a):
    print(a.get('Realtime Currency Exchange Rate').get('5. Exchange Rate')) 

while True:

    update_price_10sec(GET())
    time.sleep(10) #make function to sleep for 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move your API call into the `update_price_10sec` function. This will call it again and make sure you have your up to date price.

```
def update_price_10sec():
    # Your API call
    print(a.get('Realtime Currency Exchange Rate').get('5. Exchange Rate'))
```

If you don't call the API in your function it will only keep giving the same data you already had on the first call.

Comment: I tried but it not worked with this code, still the same issue : def update_price_10sec():
    print(a.get('Realtime Currency Exchange Rate').get('5. Exchange Rate'))
    resp = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query', params={
    'function': 'CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE',
    'from_currency': 'BTC', 
    'to_currency': 'EUR',
    'apikey': AV_API_KEY
})
resp

resp.json()

Comment: You need to reassign your 'a' variable with the json response.

Comment: I added "a=resp.json()" at the end but it did not fix the issue, I don't understand why

Comment: - do your api call
- override a
- print the data
You should build your function in that order

Comment: thank you for your help!! not an easy one